# webpack利用時、jestを実行するとCannot find moduleエラーが発生

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, jestjs

環境依存値(APIのURL)を取得するために、webpackを使用しています。

参考:
[JavaScriptでデプロイ環境ごとに設定ファイルを読み込む方法](https://aloerina01.github.io/blog/2017-02-22-1)

正しくビルド、実行されましたが、環境別の設定値を持つindex.tsを用いる機能についてjestを実行したところ、下記の通りエラーとなりました。

```
Cannot find module './_test' from 'ts/environment/index.ts'
```

フォルダ構成は参考URLとほぼ同一ですが、typescriptを利用しています。
webpackについて知見がないため、テストを実行するために必要な設定などございましたら、ご教示いただきたく思います。

Comment: 参考にされている内容とエラー内容のディレクトリ構成が異なるため、正確なディレクトリ構成と `ts/environment/index.ts` の内容、jest.config.jsの内容があると回答しやすくなるでしょう。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。webpackは無関係でした。
jest実行時、`process.env.NODE_ENV`にはデフォルトで'test'が設定されるため、実行時の値(development)と異なり、参照できないことが原因でした。